# Erro em consulta SQL com PDO

Tags: php, sql, banco-de-dados, pdo

Não consigo fazer a consulta, quando tento fazê-la, obtenho o erro:

> ```
> Erro PDOStatement Object ( [queryString] => SELECT userid FROM usuario WHERE email=:email and senha=:senha )
> ```

```
<?php
require_once('conexao.php');
// @$email = $_POST['email'];
// @$senha = $_POST['senha'];
$email = "renan-ano10@bol.com.br";
$senha = "12346";

$pdo = $dbconn->prepare("SELECT userid FROM usuario WHERE email=:email and 
senha=:senha");
$pdo->bindParam("email", $email);
$pdo->bindParam("senha", $senha);
$pdo->execute();
print_r ($pdo);

$number = $pdo->fetchColumn();
// if($pdo->rowCount() == 1) {
//     $_SESSION['login'] = ['email'];

?>
```

Comment: Qual erro está dando? na realidade você tem que colocar os dois pontos ":" no parâmetro. `$pdo->bindParam(":email", $email, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$pdo->bindParam(":senha", $senha, PDO::PARAM_STR);`

Comment: Já tentei, ele retorna isso PDOStatement Object ( [queryString] => SELECT userid FROM usuario WHERE email=:email and senha=:senha )

Comment: Sim, isso porque você está dando um `print_r` no objeto `$pdo`, segue o fluxo que é pra funcionar sim

Comment: Certo, obg. consegui

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Conseguir resolver

```
  require_once('conexao.php');
  // @$email = $_POST['email'];
  // @$senha = $_POST['senha'];
  $email = "renan-ano10@bol.com.br";
  $senha = "12346";

  $pdo = $dbconn->prepare("SELECT userid FROM usuario WHERE email=:email and 
  senha=:senha");
  $pdo->bindParam(":email", $email);
  $pdo->bindParam(":senha", $senha); 
  $pdo->execute();
  // print_r ($pdo);

  $query = $pdo->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
  print_r ($query);
```